# Preview eats first and last $ so ignores displaystyle

Tags: bug, status-completed, mathjax, design

The preview appears to be eating the first and last dollarsigns in double dollarsigned expressions hence causing displaystyle expressions to be ignored, e.g. see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10154/how-do-i-compute-x-2-mod-m/10158#10158)

Comment: sorry, I'm not following -- I don't know MathJax very well. I don't see any meaningful difference between your post, pasted in as a preview, and the final rendered post? Note that we auto-escape everything between `$..$` now though, so it should be untouched.

Comment: Even i have noticed this problem

Comment: @Jeff: It's not as glaringly obvious now since that post has been subsequently edited. But all double-dollar displaystyled LaTeX forms are now left-justified instead of centered in the preview pane.

Comment: @Jeff Atwood: I posted an example as an answer to this report.

Answer (score 4):

This has been fixed.  Was a consequence of some... uniqueness in javascript regular expressions.

Comment: Thanks for the quick fix.

Comment: [A new bug related to the `$` character has appeared](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1142/in-the-preview-the-number-of-dollar-signs-doubles-every-time-a-formula-is-used); could this fix be the cause of it?

Answer (score 0):

Example: The following equation is enclosed as `$$…$$` and therefore centered in the actual answer.

$$x=1.$$

But in preview it is left-justified.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm referring to. Thanks Tsuyoshi.