# preview ignores double dollar signs in Safari

Tags: bug, status-completed, mathjax

I'm seeing the same behaviour described in [Preview eats first and last $ so ignores displaystyle](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1128), an old bug report that's been marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) for over a year. This started about a month or two ago, and it only occurs in Safari (version 5.1.1 (6534.51.22)), not in Firefox (version 8.0.1).

In the preview, equations surrounded by double dollar signs are displayed as if they were in single dollar signs, i.e. left-justified and without display style. (If I add a third dollar sign in front, they get displayed properly, but preceded by the extra dollar sign.) This occurs only in the preview.

Comment: Same happens to me, Safari 5.1.2 (6534.52.7).

Comment: I have the reverse problem in FF8 on Windows 7. The $$ renders properly when editing, but not in the actual page.

Comment: @Suresh: My problem has been successfully fixed. If yours persists, you could write a separate bug report for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, Safari's handling of dollar signs is broken in an important place. I've added a workaround that will catch this issue; it should look correct after the next build of the site.

Comment: Thanks!${}{}{}$